# White space removed by minifier tools affects look and feel of HTML

Tags: html, web, minify

We usually add white spaces in HTML to make readable

Example – 
Development Version:

```
<div>
    <span class="surround-brackets">
        Title
    </span>
</div>
```

When above code is minimized (for prod build), we get following output

```
<div><span class="surround-brackets">Title</span></div>
```

Now, consider we have a pseudo elements added to class “surround-brackets”. Following is the CSS

```
.surround-brackets::before {
    content: "(";
}

.surround-brackets::after {
    content: ")";
}
```

Please check fiddle here - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ypbwq3s4/)

Any suggestions how to avoid such issues ?

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to minify JavaScript and CSS without adversely modifying meaning or behaviour. This is frequently not true for HTML.

`<span>` is phrasing content, which means spaces are significant.  It's actually incorrect for a HTML minifier to remove any space from within phrasing content, because you may want a CSS rule like `white-space:pre`.

Strictly, the minifier should output:

```
<div><span class="surround-brackets">
        Title
    </span></div>
```

Even if your minifier was aware of the CSS (which it shouldn't be, you can apply multiple CSS files to the same HTML), it should collapse runs of whitespace in phrasing content, but not strip them:

`<div><span class="surround-brackets"> Title </span></div>`

...the effective minified equivalent assuming normal CSS white-space processing.

You could preserve any wanted spacing in phrasing content by using `&#32;` everywhere you intentionally want a leading or trailing space, but from a maintenance point of view, I think that might be a lot of effort.

Minification of HTML is probably not important compared to using gzip. Safe minification of HTML does not save much bandwidth, about 5%. Unsafe minification may save up to 25%. Gzip is much better and usually saves at least 80%.

Comment: My question was to avoid the layout differences happens due to minification. I think we should always minify HTML in DEV mode also, so that we can avoid such discrepancies ?

Comment: @AdityaBhave Minifying HTML in DEV mode would avoid the discrepancies if it's not a costly addition to your development mode workflow.  However, I think the right approach is to avoid minification of HTML altogether. I've rewritten my answer to explain this fully.

Comment: Thanks. This answer really helps. Can you please explain what is "CSS white-space processing". In my case, output HTML is not maintaining the required white space and the brackets added through css. Since with non-minified version has a space, I applied padding of -5px on left and right. It owrked on local but not on server (minimized version of HTML). How can I make sure that the white space in this case is maintained ? Thanks.

Comment: @AdityaBhave The CSS `white-space` property has a default value of `normal`, which means sequences of white space are replaced with a single space. Since CSS only works reliably with predictable HTML, you should avoid spaces in your HTML where they adversely affect presentation. Using negative margins to compensate for spaces may not work. 5px is only the width of a space in your circumstances, other users may need a different value for how wide a space is in the font their device has selected.